# jQuery: Is another solution possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, linux, chromium

I tried to register an onClick-handler using jQuery, which functionality should be to change the query string in the URL and to launch a reload whilst I assign a new URL to window.location.href.

```
// sets a new URL with lang as query parameter indicating the language 
  setNewLang: function( lang ) {

  var that = this;

  // the url that shall be changed
  var url = window.location.href;

  // save possible other query parameters
  var tokenizedUrl = url.split("&");

  // first string in the array contains language query parameter
  var tokenZero = tokenizedUrl[0].split("l=");

  // set the new language query parameter in the first part of the url
  tokenizedUrl[0] = tokenZero[0] + "l=" + lang;

  // concatenate the splitted url
  var retVal = tokenizedUrl[0];
  for(i=1; i<tokenizedUrl.length; i++) {
    retVal = retVal + "&" + tokenizedUrl[i];
  }

  console.log(retVal);
  // reload page with new query parameter for language
  window.location = retVal; 

  return false;
}

/* language selection for navbar-right*/
    $("#navbarRightLanguageListEnglish").on("click", function() {
        console.log("DBG-INFO");    /* even the log never appears */
        that.setNewLang("en_US");
    });
```

I tried it with firefox and it worked. 
Is there a bug in chromium? Or is it a problem of scope or jQuery or ...? 
If there is another solution available to change and reload the site, I would be glad to know it.

Thanks for your help.

---

Hey folks!

I've forgotten to post the HTML and to say that I'm using bootstrap too. 
By the way, I found the bug by myself, but thank you for your help.

```
<!-- Language Selection -->
    <div id="navbarTopLanguage" class="dropdown dd-top">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" >Language<span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">

            <li id="navbarTopLanguageListEnglish" role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="">English</a></li>
            <li id="navbarTopLanguageListDeutsch" role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="">Deutsch</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- End of Language Selection -->
```

The "href"-attributes are empty and that was my fault. Chromium gives them are (wrong) value so that clicking it has not the wwanted effect.

I fixed it with changing the javascript.

```
// sets a new URL with lang as query parameter indicating the language 
setNewLang: function( id, lang ) {
    // selfie-pattern
  var that = this;

  // the url that shall be changed
  var url = window.location.href;

  // save possible other query parameters
  var tokenizedUrl = url.split("&");

  // first string in the array contains language query parameter
  var tokenZero = tokenizedUrl[0].split("l=");

  // set the new language query parameter in the first part of the url
  tokenizedUrl[0] = tokenZero[0] + "l=" + lang;

  // concatenate the splitted url
  var retVal = tokenizedUrl[0];
  for(i=1; i<tokenizedUrl.length; i++) {
    retVal = retVal + "&" + tokenizedUrl[i];
  }


  console.log(retVal);

  // reload page with new query parameter for language
  $(id).attr("href",retVal);
}
```

The new function replaces the value of the specified "href"-attribute (parameter "id") with the new URL.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please show your HTML as well (and the complete script block).

Comment: if the log never appears the click handler isn't being run.  are there any errors?  setNewLang is defined as on object, where is the surrounding code?  if it is not part of an object, use the function setNewLang(lang){} .  'that' doesn't have scope in the click handler.

Answer (score 1):

Please try

```
window.location.href = retVal;
```

instead of

```
window.location = '...'
```

If you don't want **previous URL** to go to browser history, try

```
window.location.replace(retVal)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `location.replace` is a function, not a scalar property.